# subsetting !is.na for multiple conditions unexpected results

Tags: r, subset, na

I am trying to remove rows in a df when NA appear in two specific columns.

Example dataframe

```
tmp <- data.frame(state = c(1,  1, 2,  2, 3, 3, 4, 5),
                  reg   = c(NA, 3, 6, NA, 9, 1, NA, 7),
                  gas   = c(NA, 5, NA, 9, 1, 3, NA, 1),
                  other = c(1, 2, 4, 2, 6, 8, 1, 1) )
```

from the table you can see there are two rows where both "reg" and "gas" are NA

```
table(tmp$reg, tmp$gas, useNA = 'always')
       1 3 5 9 <NA>
  1    0 1 0 0    0
  3    0 0 1 0    0
  6    0 0 0 0    1
  7    1 0 0 0    0
  9    1 0 0 0    0
  <NA> 0 0 0 1    2
```

I would like to remove these rows but retain the other NA values.

I tried this code:

```
tmp[!is.na(tmp$reg & tmp$gas), ]
```

but it removes all lines with NA in reg and gas

```
  state reg gas other
2     1   3   5     2
5     3   9   1     6
6     3   1   3     8
8     5   7   1     1
```

This is the result that I am looking for:

```
  state reg gas other
2     1   3   5     2
3     2   6  NA     4
4     2  NA   9     2
5     3   9   1     6
6     3   1   3     8
8     5   7   1     1
```

I also tried

```
tmp[which(!is.na(tmp$reg & tmp$gas)), ]
```

but that produces the same unwanted result.

Comment: You should instead treat them as separate conditions with the `AND` operator, e.g. `(!is.na(tmp$gas) & !is.na(tmp$reg))`. Does this work for you?

Comment: both of these commands

`tmp[which(!is.na(tmp$gas) & !is.na(tmp$reg)),]`


`tmp[(!is.na(tmp$gas) & !is.na(tmp$reg)),]`

produce the same unwanted result as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the initial approach didn't work, but I guess there is some fault in the chaining that I can not see. Taking the opposite approach (removing those that fulfills the condition) seems to produce the desired output.

```r
tmp <- data.frame(state = c(1,  1, 2,  2, 3, 3, 4, 5),
                  reg   = c(NA, 3, 6, NA, 9, 1, NA, 7),
                  gas   = c(NA, 5, NA, 9, 1, 3, NA, 1),
                  other = c(1, 2, 4, 2, 6, 8, 1, 1) )

res = tmp[-which(is.na(tmp$reg) & is.na(tmp$gas)),]

res
#>   state reg gas other
#> 2     1   3   5     2
#> 3     2   6  NA     4
#> 4     2  NA   9     2
#> 5     3   9   1     6
#> 6     3   1   3     8
#> 8     5   7   1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: is this a reportable bug or is this by design?